# Retaining a UIViewControllers's.view, then release VC, VC gets dealloc'd?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm creating a bunch of `UIViewControllers` for managing several custom Objects. Though I don't really need Direct access to the `UIViewController' anymore from where it was created. I want to add the viewController.view to my Master UIViewController's view.   I then release the subViewController.   The SubViewController has a gesture Recognizer in in, when I go to perform a gesture I get a Message sent to deallocated Instance.

Here is my code.

```
[...snip...]
    for (int elementForPageTypeIndex = 0 ; elementForPageTypeIndex < elementsOnPage; elementForPageTypeIndex ++){


            IoUIElementPickerElementButtonViewController * element = [[IoUIElementPickerElementButtonViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"IoUIElementPickerElementButtonViewController" bundle:nil];

            pageColumn = (elementForPageTypeIndex)%2 ;
            pageRow = roundf((elementForPageTypeIndex)/2);

            CGRect elementFrame= CGRectMake(kElementPickerColumnLeftOffset + (element.view.frame.size.width + kElementPickerColumnSeperation)*pageColumn + pageIndex*kElementPickerColumnPageOffset,
                                            kElementPickerRowTopOffset +  (kElementPickerRowSeperation + element.view.frame.size.height) * pageRow,
                                            element.view.frame.size.width,
                                            element.view.frame.size.height);

            [element.view setFrame:elementFrame];

            SysCDElement *ourCDElement = [elementsForPage objectAtIndex:elementForPageTypeIndex + maxElementsPerPages * pageIndex];

            [scrollViewContent addSubview:element.view];
            [element release];

    }
[...snip...]
```

Right after the release, The `element`'s dealloc is run.  I thought that if I retained a viewController's View that the ViewController itself would also be retained?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. It would be pretty scary if retaining the UIViewController's view also magically retained the UIViewController.

The rule of thumb is, if you need something to stay alive, you retain it. Don't ever release it if you still need it. Counting on some other class to retain it isn't dependable. If you want the controller to stay around, don't release it.

Comment: Well said. Typically "retain" here means "stick in a retaining ivar."

Comment: Thank you, that mass sense for the View Controllers. Regarding the Rule of thumb for regular UIViews. Does this rule also apply?  for instance. I create a Toolbar, There are 6 BarButtonItems on it. Depending on an event, I want to change the Icon of one of the barButton Items. I typically Create button, set properties, add to items array, then release.  I do the same thing here, though I keep the iVar that is pointing to the BartButton Item around knowing that the ToolBar Retained it even though I released the version I created. Is this acceptable?

Comment: @scooter133, That depends on the context. If you ever refer to the bar button item later, with certain expectation on what it represent, then you should retain a reference to it. If you just want to set the toolbar items and then go along your merry way, it's fine to create them and then transfer conceptual ownership to the toolbar.

Comment: I'm changing the Icon Image, think of a Locked/Unlocked Icon Image. The other situation is similar to this. I'm Adding a SubView that will contain the Gesture Recognizers for a Custom VC. I enable/disable this view if I want to enable gesture recognition. Its added as a SubView to my Main VC's View. After I add it to the vc.view I release it, though use the ivar name in other places since I know that the vc.view has retained it.  So you are saying that I should be retaining it then releasing in my dealloc. I just figured since my view will be there, so will it, so I release after I add it.

Comment: @scooter133, Yes you should retain the view. It does happen to be true that you can get away with releasing the view and not crash because you know the parent has retained it. The downside is that your reference to the subview is _only_ valid as long the parent view is still alive. There are subtle bugs just waiting to happen there. Odds are you'll be fine, but it's a better policy to just _always_ retain objects you reference later, than to try to constantly ensure that your application is in a state where a given ivar is actually a valid reference.